# Error: Class 'Flash' not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, flash-message, email-verification, laravel-facade

Actually,I am building an email verification system.

After clicking on the generated link in my email ,i am getting the above mentioned error.

error:

```
Class 'Flash' not found
```

my file: http://laravel.io/bin/jQxe6

Comment: Have you installed the `Flash` package?

Comment: tell me which package?

Comment: as you are trying to use the `Flash::message()`.

Comment: tell me the command to install flash package.Ty

Comment: Details here: https://github.com/laracasts/flash

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 0):

just install the package by following the instructions from this link :

github.com/laracasts/flash